# Django Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I've been having this error for hours and I can't seem to fix it!

URL.PY:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "learning_logg"
urlpatterns = [
    #Home Page
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

INDEX.HTML:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p> Learning Log </p>

<p> Learning Log helps you keep track of your learning, for any topic you're learning about gay </p>

{% endblock content %}
```

BASE.HTML:

```
<p>
    <a> href = "{% url "index" %}"> Learning Log</a>
</p>


{% block content%} {% endblock content %}
```

I'm trying to make base.html the main framework and then putting index.html inside it, does anyone know how to fix the error?

It says the error is in line 2:

1

2        href = "{% url "index" %}"> Learning Log
3

4
5
6   {% block content%} {% endblock content %}
7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have specified `app_name` in your `urls.py`. You should do the same when referencing the url in the url template tag like `{% url 'learning_logg:index' %}`.

See the details in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#id5).